# C# LINQ ускорить проверку листа внутри листа

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть 2 модели `House`/`Owner` и связь Многие ко многим (отдельная модель получается) `HouseToOwner`.

В `HouseToOwner` условно прописываются только Idшники дома и владельца (чтоб у дома было неск владельцев, а у владельца — неск домов).

Написал linq на поиск тех домов, которые есть у владельца:

```
        houses = houses.Where(x => x.HouseToOwner.Any(y => y.Owner.FIO.StartsWith("Вася"))).ToList();
```

Он срабатывает, но довольно долго (около 3-6сек. В бд примерно 300 домов и столько же владельцев +-).

Можно ли как то оптимизировать Linq запрос?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам надо сначала из Owner сделать выборку ID тех записей у которых выполняется условие, а потом с найденными ID уже идти выбирать из houses.

Comment: Если искать по y.Owner.Id а не по строковому FIO то насколько быстрее выполняется запрос?

Comment: @AK думаю запрос будет быстрее, но есть пустой текстбокс в который вписывается имя, а этот linq уже ищет после. хз куда здесь пристроить ID.
Выпадающий список тоже неплохое решение, но не когда в бд 300+ owner'oв

Comment: @CrazyElf ну в большей степени он реально поможет) вот только а вдруг мы решили забить на все фильтры и ищем только по ФИО?  Тогда беда

Comment: Поиском по "Вася" выводить пять найденных Вась с их ID. По клике на конкретного Васю показывать страницу, на которой уже показывать дома по этому конкретному домовладельцу. И если вы увидите, что поиск стал выполняться достаточно быстро, то можно не заниматься оптимизацией запроса (который прямо говоря придётся либо переписать с linq на чистый SQL, либо менять структуру таблиц в базе). А вам, как проектировщику уже выбирать из предложеных решений, что вам больше подходит: переделка интерфейса, написание plain sql или переделка таблиц. (Направо пойдёшь - коня потеряешь...)

Comment: Это linq to objects? Или linq to sql/entities?

Comment: Я всё-таки настаиваю, чтобы вы уточнили: вы работаете с БД или с экземплярами классов в памяти? Оптимизация кода сильно различается в том и другом случае.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а EF относится к чему из этих вариантов? Мне интересно, я правда не уверен с чем имею дело.
Скажем я получаю все записи через патерн репозиторий, выглядит примерно так:
`var houses = houseRepository.All();`
А после уже тыкаю код выше из вопроса

Comment: Мда... Вы что-то используете, но не знаете, что. | EF работает с базой данных. Но никто кроме вас не может знать, применяете вы linq-запрос к сущностям БД или к объектам в памяти. | Мне-то откуда знать, что возвращает ваш репозиторий? Это вы нам скажите, какое возвращаемое значение у `All()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать JOIN вместо IN:

```
var foundHouses =
    (from house in houses
    join houseToOwner in houseToOwners on house equals houseToOwner.House
    join owner in owners on houseToOwner.Owner equals owner
    where owner.Name.StartsWith(searchString)
    select house).ToList();
```

Comment: Время сократил с 3.6сек до 350~мс. Спасибо!